# Unable to find listener.ora in oracle 12c

Tags: location, listener, oracle12c

There is a default oracle 12c installation done in RHEL 7.5.
This is a single instance database.
When i issue lsnrctl status command i am able to see below output.

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 25-SEP-2023 15:05:00

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

### Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER

Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                08-NOV-2022 12:20:15
Uptime                    321 days 2 hr. 44 min. 44 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/cgsl-orcldb/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=cgsl-orcldb.cgsl.com)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "UATCHL" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "UATCHL", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "UATCHLXDB" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "UATCHL", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

But, I am unable to see the physical file location.
I checked in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin. But, listener.ora file is not exists.
Please let me know how to find the correct location of the file.

NOTE : $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sample --> In this location tnsnames.ora, listener.ora, sqlnet.ora files exists. But, all the details are commented and not related to existing connection details.

I want to know the physical file location of listener.ora in oracle 12c

Comment: There are two possibilities: 1) You have multiple version of Oracle installed, and thus a second `ORACLE_HOME` directory, or 2) your listener is using an alternate location for the network configuration files, identified by the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable.

Comment: 1) We have installed only one version of oracle sw (12c).    2) Now, how to identify that alternate location used by listener ? Please guide

Comment: If this is a fresh installation then there shouldn't be an alternate location: you would have had to set that up specifically. Running the installer should have guided you through the database creation assistant and network configuration assistants, which should have set all of those files up for the first time. If you're just looking for the file, you can always use the `find` command: `find / -name "listener.ora" -print`